# delegate is nil when I change view

Tags: ios, swift, menu, delegates

I have 2 way to access at the another pages on my app:

- *slide out* OR *tap on icon menu* to open my slide out navigation panel;
- Links are on the first page.

[image]

But when I change view, from the slide out navigation panel or the links on my first page, the delegate equals to nil, you can try my app here:

https://github.com/Vkt0r/SlideOutSideBarTest

So, I can't open my slide out navigation panel when I tap on the icon menu:
[image]

I see "lol" message on console, but my menu won't open, and here my delegate equals to nil, and I think that's why I couldn't use my toggleLeftPanel function, so how to do ?

```
@IBAction func menuTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("lol")
    delegate?.toggleLeftPanel?()
}
```

Comment: Your github link isn't working. Are you sure the delegate is nil? Since the function is optional it perhaps isn't implemented? Where are you setting the delegate?